# Приложение, способное восстановиться после убийства системой

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь создать приложение, которое при получении телефоном входящего смс считывает его содержимое плюс номер и записывает в свою *БД*. Информацию о поступлении смс приложение получает через `BroadcastReceiver`, работая в фоновом режиме.

Требуется следующее: приложение должно восстанавливаться после того, как система убьет его из-за нехватки ресурсов.

Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавьте в onCreate вашей основной активити:

```
intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(YourApplication.getInstance().getBaseContext(), 0,
            new Intent(getIntent()), getIntent().getFlags());
```

И в `uncaughtException()`

```
AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 2000, intent);
System.exit(2);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, про PendingIntent даже не знал до этого момента. А вот с ALARM_SERVICE такая идея была, просто сначала показалась костыльной и подумал придержать на крайний случай, если не найдется другого способа. Буду реализовывать.